# SignalR UseServiceBus deinition missing after upgrading to .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, upgrade, servicebus

I have had to update a project from .NET 4.0 to 4.6.1 for irrelevant reasons.

After the upgrade, a number of nuget packages had to be reinstalled due to having been installed under the old framework prior.

All is well aside from the compiler not liking my old SignalR configuration:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connString, "notifications");
```

UseServiceBus() is undefined.

Edit:

I forgot that the compiler no longer finds this cache property: WebAPI.OutputCache.Cache.MemoryCacheDefault() - Cache is undefined.

```
var cacheConfig = new global::WebAPI.OutputCache.CacheOutputConfiguration(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        cacheConfig.RegisterCacheOutputProvider(() => new global::WebAPI.OutputCache.Cache.MemoryCacheDefault());
```

One thing to mention is that previously I was running SignalR v1.1.2, but nuget no longer has this version so I opted for 1.1.4.

Any ideas? The MSDN documentation, while old, still instructs to use this method, so I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes you just have to admit it when you make a rookie mistake, and this is one of those times.

I was missing the SignalR.ServiceBus dll.

I removed it to reinstall it and forgot because it's not included in the main package for SignalR.